# I'm having a problem with my code. It only prints one of the two values in the hand

Tags: python, global-variables, global

I'm making a card game and I wanted to make a function that prints the value of the cards in the hand. However, it only prints the value of the last card picked up.

I've tried counting the value of the cards in a different function from the on used to pick up a card with the same results.

The Deck and Variables:

```
heartsCards = ["Ace of Hearts","Two of Hearts","Three of Hearts","Four of Hearts","Five of Hearts","Six of Hearts","Seven of Hearts","Eight of Hearts","Nine of Hearts","Ten of Hearts","Jack of Hearts","Queen of Hearts","King of Hearts"]
diamondsCards = ["Ace of Diamonds","Two of Diamonds","Three of Diamonds","Four of Diamonds","Five of Diamonds","Six of Diamonds","Seven of Diamonds","Eight of Diamonds","Nine of Diamonds","Ten of Diamonds","Jack of Diamonds","Queen of Diamonds","King of Diamonds"]
clubsCards = ["Ace of Clubs","Two of Clubs","Three of Clubs","Four of Clubs","Five of Clubs","Six of Clubs","Seven of Clubs","Eight of Clubs","Nine of Clubs","Ten of Clubs","Jack of Clubs","Queen of Clubs","King of Clubs"]
spadesCards = ["Ace of Spades","Two of Spades","Three of Spades","Four of Spades","Five of Spades","Six of Spades","Seven of Spades","Eight of Spades","Nine of Spades","Ten of Spades","Jack of Spades","Queen of Spades","King of Spades"]

yourCards = []
cardValue = 0
```

pickUp Function:

```
def pickUp():
    randomNum = random.randint(1,4)
    global cardValue

    if randomNum == 1:
        temp = random.choice(heartsCards)
        if heartsCards.index(temp) < 10:
            cardValue =+ heartsCards.index(temp) + 1
        else:
            cardValue =+ 10
        yourCards.append(temp)
        heartsCards.remove(temp)

    if randomNum == 2:
        temp = random.choice(diamondsCards)
        if diamondsCards.index(temp) < 10:
            cardValue =+ diamondsCards.index(temp) + 1
        else:
            cardValue =+ 10
        yourCards.append(temp)
        diamondsCards.remove(temp)

    if randomNum == 3:
        temp = random.choice(clubsCards)
        if clubsCards.index(temp) <10:
            cardValue =+ clubsCards.index(temp) + 1
        else:
            cardValue =+ 10
        yourCards.append(temp)
        clubsCards.remove(temp)

    if randomNum == 4:
        temp = random.choice(spadesCards)
        if spadesCards.index(temp) < 10:
            cardValue =+ spadesCards.index(temp) + 1
        else:
            cardValue =+ 10
        yourCards.append(temp)
        spadesCards.remove(temp)
```

cardCount Function:

```
def cardCount():
    temp = 0
    global cardValue

    for card in yourCards:
        if card.count("Ace"):
            temp =+ 1

    if temp == 0:
        print ("The value of your cards is",str(cardValue) + ".")

    if temp == 1:
        print ("The value of your cards is",cardValue,"or",str(cardValue + 10) , ".")

    if temp == 2:
        print ("The value of your cards is",cardValue,"or",str(cardValue + 10),"or",str(cardValue + 10) , ".")
```

After calling cardCount() with a deck of two cards, the only value printed is the value of the latter card. e.g. with a deck of the 2 of Hearts and the 8 of Spades, the function prints the value as 8.

Comment: If you define `val = []` then add `val.append(cardValue)` at the end of each if statement you get a list with the values in hand. I suppose your question is why `cardValue` isn't incremented, isn't it?

Comment: @iGian I don't follow?

Comment: Did I get the problem you are facing? I mean `cardValue` isn't incremented. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the problem happens because cardValue is not incremented.

In your code there is `cardValue =+ heartsCards.index(temp) + 1` or `cardValue =+ 10` which is not correct.

Change everywhere to `cardValue += whatever`

---

This is increments the variable:

```
a = 10
a += 100
print(a) #=> 110
```

This assigns the value:

```
a =+ 1
print(a) #=> 1
# same as a = +1
```

Comment: I don't understand how it works but it does so thanks :)

Comment: I added an explanation.